# Template override form fields in com_user

Tags: template-override

I want to override the login page (com_users/login). I want to add new class to the 2 fields (username and password) and also if possible to change the structure from

```
<label></label>
<input>
```

to

```
<label><input><label>
```

But in the `templates/template/html/com_users/login/default_login.php` they are called like this :

```
echo $ this-> form-> renderFieldset ('credentials');
```

I found that the fields are loaded from this file `/components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml`

I tried to copy that file to 
`templates/template/code/com_users/models/forms/login.xml` but still doesn't work.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

To change field attributes you have to modify the form. This is normally done using a plugin with `onContentPrepareForm` event. But if the changes are only cosmetic I guess this could be done in the layout too.

To add another class to `username` field:

```
$this->form->setFieldAttribute('username', 'class', $this->form->getFieldAttribute('username', 'class') . ' myClass');
```

To change how fields are rendered make overrides of `layouts/joomla/form/renderfield.php` and `layouts/joomla/form/renderlabel.php`. Layout overrides can be global or component-specific. If you want to make the changes only to `com_users` place the overrides in `templates/your_template/layouts/com_users/joomla/form`. Note, this will affect all forms in `com_users`.